# SQL Nested query searching multiple fields

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can anyone help with a nested query I'm using in a VB form as I am struggling.

So the first part of the query is as follows.

```
select 
    [incidentid] as incidentid, 
    ('Incident' &' '&[incidentID] &' '&'has a new containment') as incisearch 
from 
    containment 
where 
    transtime > @logout
```

This works fine, and will return the correct information. What I would like to do is search against another parameter which is `@username`.

This information is held in a table called `incident` and the `@username` paramater can be found in either the `incidentowner`, `purchasingmember` or `additionalmember` fields.

Basically I want the query to return results if a containment has been entered after the user which can be found in `incidentowner`, `purchasingmember` or `additionalmember` has last logged on.

So here is what I have tried so far:

```
select 
    [incidentid] as incidentid, 
    ('Incident' &' '&[incidentID] &' '&'has a new containment') as incisearch 
from 
    containment 
where 
    transtime > @logout and 
    purchasingmember in 
       (select 
            [incidentid] 
        from 
            incident 
        where 
            purchasingmember = @username)
```

I thought at first I would try it just by searching for one field rather than several, this returns the error

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

I then also tried searching for several fields at once using the following

```
select 
    [incidentid] as incidentid, 
    ('Incident' &' '&[incidentID] &' '&'has a new containment') as incisearch 
from 
    containment 
where 
    transtime > @logout and 
    @username in 
       (select 
            [incidentid] 
        from 
            incident 
        where 
            (incidentowner = @username) or 
            (purchasingmember = @username) or 
            (additionalmember = @username))
```

This query doesn't fail but it doesn't return any results and I am expecting to return exactly one. So this query isn't broken I just don't think I've told it what to search for correctly. Can anyone help?

From receiving comments below I have also amended to try the following code but it is still not working as intended

```
select 
    [incidentid] as incidentid, 
    ('Incident' &' '&[incidentID] &' '&'has a new containment') as incisearch 
from 
    containment 
where 
    transtime > @logout and 
    incidentid in 
       (select 
            [incidentid] 
        from 
            incident 
        where 
            (incidentowner = @username) or 
            (purchasingmember = @username) or 
            (additionalmember = @username))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do something like `... @INCIDENTID in (select [indientid] from incident where ...` ? You're searchin username in incidentid list!

Comment: are you sure about your clause  **@username** in (...) ? you are checking parameter @username against IN Query

Comment: @LS_dev I have added a new query hopefully correcting that mistake but it is still not returning a result as I expect, are you able to tell me where I am going wrong? at no point is the query checking that the incidentid in containment matches the incidentid in incident

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` and build your query slowly checking it each time to see what the results are. `JOIN` your `incident` table to the `containment` table...`from containment inner join incident on containment.incidentid = incident.incidentid` and see what that returns. If nothing then check both tables have the record you want.

Comment: @Jinx88909 Thankyou, I was missing something and couldn't figure out what,  this has helped immensely

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jinx88909 I managed to solve this, the correct SQL command should have been

```
select 
     containment.incidentid as incidentid, 
     ('Incident' &' '& containment.incidentID &' '&'has a new containment') as incisearch 
from 
     (containment INNER JOIN incident ON containment.incidentid = incident.incidentid) 
where 
     containment.transtime > @logout and 
     (incident.incidentowner = @username or incident.purchasingmember = @username or incident.additionalmember = @username)
```